# Equivalence for direct sum of vector subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a lot of problems proving the following statement.

> Let $V$ be a vector space. Let $W,K\leq V,$ where $\leq$ denotes vector subspaces.
>
> $W\bigoplus K=V$ $\iff$ $K\leq V$ and is least element with the property $W+K=V.$

The proposition $\implies$ I got it. It's enough to prove that is least element.

Let $S\leq V$ such as $S\subset K.$ Then $K\cap(S+W)=S\cap(K+W),$ so $$K\cap(S+W)=S\cap V= S.$$ Note that, if $S+W=V$ We have $K=S.$ Therefore $K$ is least element with the property $W+K=V.$

My problem is the other implication. I cannot see a path to solve it. My attempt was to use contradiction but I don't achive get something useful.

Any kind of help will be thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that the implication is false. Then there exists $v\in V$ such that there exist distinct $w_1,w_2\in W$ and $k_1,k_2\in K$ such that $w_1+k_1=v$ and $w_2+k_2=v$. Then $W + K\setminus\{k_2\}=V$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How did you conclude $W+K\\{k_{2}\}=V?$

Comment: @Suiz346 two subsets add to $V$ if for any $v\in V$, I can find two elements, one each subset, which together make $V$. What I have shown is that it is possible to remove an element from $K$, and you can still add it to $W$ to get $V$. Anytime you have something like $u+k_2=x$, where $u\in W$ and $x\in V$, you also have $u+w_1-w_2+k_1=x$, so you don't need $k_2$.

Comment: I got it! Thanks @Alex S. :) Your answer is very clear!